# why did this error occur when argument is under the scope of the function f()?

Tags: python, function, oop

```
def f(a, *arguments):
    for arg in arguments:
        print(arg)
    return arg
f(5)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    f(5)
  File "test.py", line 5, in f
    return arg
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'arg' referenced before assignment
```

if you change the function f() like this

```
def f(a, *arguments):
    for arg in range(1,4):
        print(arg)
    return arg
f(5)
```

the output is this:

```
1
2
3
```

now arg is global in the function. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(a, *arguments):
    for arg in arguments:
        print(arg)
    return arg


f(5)
```

Since *arguments is empty, you never enter the loop.  Thus, when you reach `return(arg)` the variable is still undefined.  Try calling it with `f(5, [1, 2, 3])` and you'll see something more like your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

@Prune's answer is apt for your question. You may still want to return something even if `arguments` is empty. You can do so by adding a check for arguments length.

```
def f(a, *arguments):
    if len(arguments):
        for arg in arguments:
            print(arg)
        return arg # will return last element in arguments always
    return -1 # will return default value here

f(5)
```